# How to import the textfields and buttons from class GUI to Controleur?

Tags: javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I tried to import the textfields and buttons from class `GUI` into class `Controleur` but I cannot do it. How to do it? Any answer will appreciates.

I have class `GUI`:

```
public class GUI implements IView{

     TextField textfield1;
     TextField textfield2;
     TextField textfield3;
     TextField textfield4;
     TextField textfield5;


    public void View() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            AnchorPane anchorPane= new AnchorPane();

            textfield1.setPrefHeight(27.0);
            textfield1.setPrefWidth(400.0);
            textfield1.setLayoutY(109.0);
            textfield1.setEditable(false);
            textfield1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            textfield1.setId("textfield1");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(textfield1);

            //TextField textfield2= new TextField();
            textfield2.setPrefHeight(27.0);
            textfield2.setPrefWidth(400.0);
            textfield2.setLayoutY(82.0);
            textfield2.setEditable(false);
            textfield2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            textfield2.setId("textfield2");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(textfield2);

            textfield3.setPrefHeight(27.0);
            textfield3.setPrefWidth(400.0);
            textfield3.setLayoutY(55.0);
            textfield3.setEditable(false);
            textfield3.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            textfield3.setId("textfield3");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(textfield3);

            textfield4.setPrefHeight(27.0);
            textfield4.setPrefWidth(400.0);
            textfield4.setLayoutY(28.0);
            textfield4.setEditable(false);
            textfield4.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            textfield4.setId("textfield4");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(textfield4);

            //TextField textfield5= new TextField();
            textfield5.setPrefHeight(20.0);
            textfield5.setPrefWidth(400.0);
            textfield5.setLayoutY(1.0);
            textfield5.setEditable(false);
            textfield5.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
            textfield5.setId("textfield5");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(textfield5);

            Button button7 = new Button("7");
            button7.setPrefHeight(34.0);
            button7.setPrefWidth(82.0);
            button7.setLayoutY(207.0);
            button7.setLayoutX(21.0);
            button7.setMnemonicParsing(false);
            button7.setId("seven");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(button7);

            Button button4 = new Button("4");
            button4.setPrefHeight(34.0);
            button4.setPrefWidth(82.0);
            button4.setLayoutY(241.0);
            button4.setLayoutX(21.0);
            button4.setMnemonicParsing(false);
            button4.setId("four");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(button4);

            Button button1 = new Button("1");
            button1.setPrefHeight(34.0);
            button1.setPrefWidth(82.0);
            button1.setLayoutY(275.0);
            button1.setLayoutX(21.0);
            button1.setMnemonicParsing(false);
            button1.setId("one");
            anchorPane.getChildren().add(button1);


            Scene sc = new Scene(anchorPane, 400.0, 375.0);
}
```

and class `Controleur`:

```
public class Controleur {

//code to connect with those textfields and buttons from class GUI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create instance of Controller in your GUI constructor

```
public class View extends Application {
 public View() {
 Controller controller = new Controller(this);
  //here all declaration and stuff...
  Button button = new Button();
  button.setOnAction(controller);
 }
}
```

And then in Controller instance of your GUI class:

```
public class Controller implements EventListener {
 View parent;
 public Controller(View parent) {
  this.parent = parent;
 }
 public void handle(Event event) {
   Object ob = event.getSource();
   if( ob == parent.button ) {
    String data = parent.textField.getText();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: if my controller has to manipulate with view and model how can i write it?

Comment: @Schrodinger pls show what you have done so far

Comment: I want to add View and Model for the public controller(View Parent, Accumulateur ac){} so what should i change with the Controller controleur=new Controller(this)?

Comment: As I said , you should pass reference of your View class where you declared all your objects to another classes (controller and model) to communicate between these classes through this reference and pass values to any objects, see example above.

Comment: here I have done so far. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578482/how-to-define-an-object-to-match-with-the-class-controleur-from-class-gui